# How to do a nested when in a trigger in sql?

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, nested, case-when

What is wrong with this statement? It says I get an error at 'WHEN' I need to check to make sure there is no foreign key issue and after, I need to check whether the foreign key issue comes from a mistake from inputting data in the wrong table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger3
            BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
            FOR EACH ROW
                WHEN ((SELECT flowers.comname FROM flowers WHERE comname = NEW.name) IS NULL) 
                BEGIN
                    WHEN ((SELECT genus, species FROM flowers WHERE CONCAT(species,' ',genus) = NEW.name) IS NOT NULL)
                    THEN
                        INSERT INTO sightings VALUES (comname, NEW.person, NEW.location, NEW.sighted)
                    END IF;
                END; 
            END;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `IF` instead of `WHEN`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger3
            BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
            FOR EACH ROW
                BEGIN
                    IF ((SELECT flowers.comname FROM flowers WHERE comname = NEW.name) IS NULL) 
                    BEGIN
                        IF ((SELECT genus, species FROM flowers WHERE CONCAT(species,' ',genus) = NEW.name) IS NOT NULL)
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO sightings VALUES (comname, NEW.person, NEW.location, NEW.sighted)
                        END ;
                    END; 
                END;
            END;
```

Comment: @BrandonWand, try again

Comment: doesn't work, maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm using sqlite?